# Search by Letters using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

hi i m using Linq & C# and i want to filter my data as this syntax in Sql
Syntax in sql is
I hav one table name Customer in which name is field
'Select name from customer where name like 'C%''
can u help to solve this code in Linq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcard search for LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040380/wildcard-search-for-linq) and [Like query ing LINQ to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742667/like-query-ing-linq-to-object)

Answer (score 1):

Also check

```
 StartsWith
   EndsWith
```

another alternate

```
 var query = from c in ctx.Customers
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.City, "L_n%")
                select c;
```

same question : [Like query ing LINQ to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742667/like-query-ing-linq-to-object/2742711#2742711)